# Is there a way to get regional time format with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

as I tried to ask in my title, I am talking about regional time format. I have an application that can display the time/date, but from US users I get the question of why am I displaying the time like this: **21:30** instead of this: 9:30PM. Same thing for the date to which I display the date as **22.05.2018** instead of **05.22.2018**.

So my questions is: Is there a way to achieve getting a timezone flag or location or even the time already formatted so that I can display the time/date different for different regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Boost Locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/locale/doc/html/formatting_and_parsing.html)

```
double now=time(0);
cout << as::datetime << as::local_time << "Local time is: "<< now << endl;
cout << as::gmt << "GMT Time is: "<< now <<endl;
cout << as::time_zone("EST") << "Eastern Standard Time is: "<< now <<endl;
```

Parse date from string back and add the time-zone

Comment: Hello @Victor Gubin, is the std::locale an equivalent?

Comment: [boost locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/locale/doc/html/std_locales.html) simply implementing right facets for the std::locale functionality.